# How to display the time after a function has finished

Tags: python, function, time, tkinter, label

The following code chooses a word from a list and displays it on a label. I also have a label which displays the time which is update once the user presses the enter key.

```
import tkinter
import time
import random

score = 0
words = ["Games","Development","Keyboard","Speed","Typer","Anything","Alpha","Zealous","Accurate","Basics","Shortcut","Purpose","Window","Counter","Fortress","Modification","Computer","Science","History","Football","Basketball","Solid","Phantom","Battlefield","Advanced","Warfare","Download","Upload","Antidisestablishmentarianism","Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious","Discombobulation","Liberated","Assassin","Brotherhood","Revelation","Unity","Syndicate","Victory"]
wordcount = 0

start_time = time.time()

def shuffle():
    global word, score, start_time
    now = time.time()
    score = float(start_time - now)
    score = round(score,2)
    while wordcount < 12:
        entry.delete(0, tkinter.END)
        word = random.choice(words)
        label.config(text=str(word))
        scoreLabel.config(text="Time: " + str(score) + "s")      
        return

def check(event):
    global score, wordcount, word, start_time
    now = time.time()
    score = float(start_time - now)
    score = round(score,2)
    if entry.get().lower() == word.lower():
        scoreLabel.config(text="Time: " + str(score) + "s")
        wordcount += 1
        wordcounter.config(text="Words: " + str(wordcount))
        words.remove(word) 
        shuffle()

    elif entry.get().lower() != word.lower():
        scoreLabel.config(text="Time: " + str(score) + "s")
        shuffle()                                

root = tkinter.Tk()          
label = tkinter.Label(root, font=('Helvetica', 32))
label.pack()
scoreLabel = tkinter.Label(root, text="Time: " + str(score) + "s", font=('Helvetica', 14))
scoreLabel.pack()
wordcounter = tkinter.Label(root, text="Words: " + str(wordcount), font =("Helvetica", 14))
wordcounter.pack()                                   
go = tkinter.Button(root, text="GO!", command=shuffle)
go.pack()
entry = tkinter.Entry(root)
root.bind("<Return>", check)
entry.pack()
entry.focus_set()
root.mainloop()
```

My problem is that whenever they press enter key, the time is shown in a negative value which is wrong. I have also tried (Last two aren't any different):

```
score = float(now - start_time)
score = float(start_time + now)
score = float(now + start_time)
```

But still produces the wrong output(negative values).

Comment: `timeit` might be better suited for this perhaps. https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html

Comment: unrelated: (1) `global` usage is incorrect. Don't write `global start_time` in a function unless you see `start_time = ...` in that function. (2) convert the set of related functions (with the same `global` statements) into methods and use instance attributes instead of globals (3) use `time.monotonic()` instead of `time.time()` to measure elapsed time.

Answer (score 1):

`start_time` will always be a smaller number than `now`. You should be reversing your subtraction.

```
score = float(now - start_time)
```

Comment: I've tried this but still produces something like `-34s`